# How to make a invites command (Discord.js)

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

**Hello, I am currently wondering how to make a invites command for my discord bot.**

How it would work will be I use n!invites and it comes with
You have (num) invites.

I would like it to be the amount of invites the user has gained.

If I could get some help here that would be appreciated. Thanks.

*Note I have looked at the the discord.js website and there is a place for it but I never understood.*

Comment: Maybe you'd want to specify what exactly these invites that you're referring to are? Amount of custom invite links they've created for the server, or?

Comment: I would like it to be the amount of invites the user has gained.

Comment: I think I know Discord pretty well, and I haven't got the slightest clue what you're talking about. How does one "gain invites" in a Discord server?

Comment: So basically. A user invites users and after the user joined when the user would use !invites it would come up with how many joins they have. Take invite manager for an example.

Comment: Ok, so how many times a specific user's invite link has been used is what you're asking. I see. Well what have you tried? Anything? The stuff on the Discord.js [documentation on it](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchInvites) seems pretty clear to me. Get all the invites for the guild and then pull [`inviter`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Invite?scrollTo=inviter) and [`uses`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Invite?scrollTo=uses) from each one, if it's available.

Comment: To me i don’t understand, by any chance could you give an example?

Comment: I don't know javascript that well. I've been writing Discord bots in C# for a few years, but in js. I'm not trying to be rude like "no I wont help you". I would give you an example if I could. But I think your problem here mostly is just not yet being very experienced with javascript. I recommend maybe learning it a bit more. If you can't be asked, Google for some discord.js bot source codes and have a look what other people have been doing. There's something to be learned from copying other people as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code I found on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59111190/how-can-i-check-mentioned-user-invites-with-this-discord-js-code)

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.content === "n!invites"){
        var user = message.author;

        message.guild.fetchInvites()
        .then

        (invites =>
            {
                const userInvites = invites.array().filter(o => o.inviter.id === user.id);
                var userInviteCount = 0;
                for(var i=0; i < userInvites.length; i++)
                {
                    var invite = userInvites[i];
                    userInviteCount += invite['uses'];
                }
                     message.reply(`You have ${userInviteCount} invites.`);
            }
        )
    }
});
```

It gets every invite links from the guild using

```
message.guild.fetchInvites()
```

and finds an invite link that was created by the **user** which is the author, in this case, using a filter

```
const userInvites = invites.array().filter(o => o.inviter.id === user.id);
```

Using a for loop, it adds the amount of invites the **user** has until the invites the **user** has matches it.

```
var userInviteCount = 0;
for(var i=0; i < userInvites.length; i++)
{
    var invite = userInvites[i];
    userInviteCount += invite['uses'];
}
```

Then it adds the amount of uses to the **userInviteCount** statement which will be **0** if there is no invite found made by the user or the **user** has not invited anybody to the server.

Finally is sends a reply with the amount of invites the **user** has

```
message.reply(`You have ${userInviteCount} invites.`);
```

It is in a Template String so you don't have to put + but instead put ${expression} which is **userInviteCount**, so the amount of invites the **user** has.

Comment: If you could explain your answer a bit more instead of just posting code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the command you're looking for would look something like this:

```js
    if (message.content === 'n!invites') {

        var userId = message.author.id;

        var userInvites = message.guild.fetchInvites().then(invites => invites.find(invite => invite.inviter.id === userId));

        var useAmount = userInvites.uses;

        if (useAmount === undefined) {

            message.channel.send(`${message.author.username} has 0 invites`);
        }

        else {

            message.channel.send(`${message.author.username} has ${useAmount} invites`);
        }
    }
```