# How can i add role when member has 10 invites?

Tags: discord, discord.js

im making discord bot with discord.js v12 and im trying to give role when member has 10 invites

i found invitation code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59594196/how-to-make-a-invites-command-discord-js) and modified it:

```
if(message.channel.type != "dm" && message.channel.id === '768475421953915093') {
message.delete();
var user = message.author;

    message.guild.fetchInvites()
    .then

    (invites =>
        {
            const userInvites = invites.array().filter(o => o.inviter.id === user.id);
            var userInviteCount = 0;
            for(var i=0; i < userInvites.length; i++)
            {
                var invite = userInvites[i];
                userInviteCount += invite['uses'];
            }
                if(userInviteCount >= 10){
                const guildMember = message.member;
                guildMember.addRole('767542365812886656');
                message.author.send(`you have access now`)
            }else {
              message.author.send(`sry u have ${userInviteCount} invitations. u need at least five`)
            }
    }
    )
 }
```

yes, it works but you can trick the system easily. If you keep rejoining from the server, the invite counter increases. How can i stop that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you will need an external database since Discord API doesn't provide any information about **who** used that invite and **how many times**.

**ALERT: It's a simple feature but can be very hard for people that don't have any coding experience, so if it's your first project, don't give up and keep trying! :D**

You can use [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas), which is very simples and free.

And the logic will be very simple:

1 - Create a collection to store the invites data, you can do something like in [this example](https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/coding-guides/tracking-used-invites.md)

2 - Create a collection (you can give any name, but in this example, I will refer to this collection as `new_members`) to store the new members data, it should have the fields `serverId` (to store the guild ID), `userId` (to store the user ID) and `inviteCode` (to store the invite code or url)

3 - When a user joins the discord server, it will trigger the "guildMemberAdd" event, and you will get the invite that was used (with the example that I give in the first step), and create a new doc in the `new_members` collection.

4 - After creating this new data, you will search for all the docs from the same invite, and filter them by userId (there are many ways to do this, [this is one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43374112/filter-unique-values-from-an-array-of-objects)).

5 - With this array of docs, you can use his length to determine how many people were invited, and give the role.

**VERY SIMPLE EXAMPLE, THAT SHOULDN'T BE USED:**

```js
DiscordClient.on("guildMemberAdd", async (member) => {
  /**
   * https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/coding-guides/tracking-used-invites.md
   * Here you will get the invite that was used, and store in the "inviteCode" variable
   */
  const inviteCode = await getInviteUsed()

  await NewMemberRepository.insert({
    serverId: member.guild.id,
    userId: member.id,
    inviteCode: inviteCode
  });

  const joinedMembersFromTheInvite = await NewMemberRepository.find({
    inviteCode: inviteCode
  });

  /**
   * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43374112/filter-unique-values-from-an-array-of-objects
   * Here you will filter the results by userId
   */
  const invitesWithUniqueUsers = filterJoinedMembersByUserId(joinedMembers)

  if (invitesWithUniqueUsers >= REQUIRED_INVITES_QTD) {
    /**
     * Gives the role to the creator of the invite
     */
  }
});
```

Hope it helps, good luck! :D

---

**OBS:**

- Yes, Discord API provides how many times an invite was used, but not how many a specific person used this invite.
- In the examples, I used something like [TypeORM](https://typeorm.io/), but if you are using JavaScript instead TypeScript, you can use [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/)

Comment: i saw the answer a bit late like 4 years thanks for the answer tho